# Collecting from arduino pin for specific time interval

Tags: loops, time, arduino, sampling

I want to run my Arduino for a specific amount of time (say 60 seconds) and collect
data from the analog pin with a specific sampling rate (say four samples a second).
I got the code working in matlab... but I want to use the arduino environment. 
Please help me convert it.

```
a_pin = 0;

fs = 4;   % sampling frequency (samplings per second)
mt = 20;  % time for measurements

ind = 1;
nind = 1;
last_beep = 0;
tic;
while toc < mt

    time(ind) = toc;
    v(ind) = a.analogRead(a_pin);

    % wait for appropriate time for next measurement
    while( nind == ind )
        nind = floor(toc*fs) + 1;
    end
    ind = nind;

end
```

Ok this is what i have so far in my sketch. Would this measure for 10 seconds taking
readings every 5?

```
int sensePin = 0;
unsigned long starttime = 0;
unsigned long endtime = 0;
int i = 0;
int n;
const int sizeofv = 50;
int v[sizeofv];

void setup(){
    pinMode(sensePin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    starttime = millis();
    endtime = starttime; 

    while ((endtime - starttime) <= 10000) // do this loop for up to 1000mS
    {
        i = i + 1;
        v[i] = analogRead(sensePin);
        endtime = millis();
        delay(5000);
    }  

    for(n=0; n < sizeofv; n++)
    {
        Serial.print(v[n]);
        Serial.print('\n');
    }
    while(1) { }
}
```

Comment: Probably best if you try to convert it yourself first and come back if you get stuck. Start with one of the example sketches that comes with the arduino ide, and be sure to check the good language reference on http://arduino.cc

Comment: ok i shared what i have so far. not sure if it is doing what i want though

Comment: Without running it, I think what you have will more or less work. Couple small comments... You can actually do all of that in the setup() function and leave off the while(1) loop at the end. You can also replace your second Serial.print with Serial.println(). To help debug/test the code, you could add a Serial.println debug statement prior to each analog read.. Then check the timings are what you expect.

Comment: One more... You should move where you update endtime to after call to delay()

Comment: is there a quick way to have my array 'v' exported to say a .mat file?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [SimpleTimer](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer) library, it does all the work for you and is road proven.

Answer (score 0):

- There's one bug in your code, you're incrementing `i` prior to assigning the first value. So when you'll loop over the `v[]` array, you'll end up printing `v[0]` which will have an undefined value, and you'll never print the last recorded value of `v` (if you did not end up overflow the buffer and write outside its boundaries).
- There's one glitch with your code, it's that you make a condition that you need to end it at 10000, and you make two delays of 5000. Theoretically it looks ok, but in practice, you may get a surprise having only one value. That's because code takes time to execute, and an `analogRead()` is particularly slow.

I think using loops within the `loop()` function make things more complicated, and add close to no flexibility. So here you have another take you could try, to use the `loop()` only by tracking states of the loop, based on some simple calculations:

```
#define TIME_WINDOW 10000
#define NB_STEPS 2

void setup() {
    // ...
    endtime = millis();
}

bool over = false;
void loop() {
    if (!over) {
        curtime = endtime - millis();

        // get in this block for up to 1000mS
        if (curtime <= TIME_WINDOW) {
            v[i] = analogRead(sensePin);
            // increments only once when 5000 has been reached.
            if ((curtime / (TIME_WINDOW/NB_STEPS)) != i)
                i = (curtime / (TIME_WINDOW/NB_STEPS));
        } else {
            for(n=0; n < NB_STEPS; n++)
                Serial.println(v[n]);
            over = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not test my code, so it may fail or have typos, but the idea is the following:

- we define the time window and the number of measure steps
- while the time window is not over:

  - store the measurement in the current array at current index
  - if integer division of spent time over time_window is different from current index

    - store the new value into the current index
    - e.g.: `i = 4000/(10000/2) <=> i = 4000/5000 <=> i = 0` and `i = 6000/(10000/2) <=> i = 1`
- when the time window is over:

  - print out each result
  - set over to true thus we're not entering the loop again

But a simpler (non flexible) solution for you would be:

```
void setup() {
    int value1, value2, value3, value4;
    value1 = analogRead(sensePin);
    delay(2500);
    value2 = analogRead(sensePin);
    delay(2500);
    value3 = analogRead(sensePin);
    delay(2500);
    value4 = analogRead(sensePin);
    Serial.println("first value: %d", value1);
    Serial.println("second value: %d", value2);
    Serial.println("third value: %d", value3);
    Serial.println("fourth value: %d", value4);
}
```

and there you got your solution!

HTH